# How to make an HTTP request from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an async **HTTP** request from the **HTML**, parse a response, and update an HTML page respectively. Is there a way to do it without using AJAX or any other third-party library?

I'd like to find the most basic way to do this.
Since libraries can do it, it should be possible without them too.

Worth saying, that I'm a mobile developer who checks web development for a couple of days.

**UPDATE 1**

I didn't have to call AJAX a "third-party library". My bad.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks everybody who responded. What I've learned: the only way to do what I wanted is AJAX, in particular, **XMLHttpRequest**.

Comment: Ajax is the name given to the process of "Making an HTTP request with JavaScript without leaving the current page". You can't do it without Ajax because they are the same thing. Ajax is not a third party library. Anything you can do with a library you can do without one because a library is just "JavaScript that someone else wrote".

Comment: You want it to be asynchronous but don't want AJAX? That is kind of weird, since AJAX literally means "Asynchronous Javascript and XML" (although you can ignore the XML part)

Comment: Here you have got browser api docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: With ajax only you can if you dont want to use jquery ajax you can always opt for `promise`

Comment: @AatifBandey — That makes no sense at all. A promise isn't a way to make an HTTP request.

Comment: You can't. AJaX is not a third party library. And HTML is not a scripting/programming language, only a text formatting language.

Comment: @Quentin yes i know i was referring for aysnc tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way without JS. The most basic way is to either use the new `fetch()` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or good old `XMLHttpRequest()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: This link is also good ;) : https://davidwalsh.name/fetch

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Technically it is possible to request external resources without JS, but not to accomplish what the OP wants to do...but in case anyone is curious: http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/

Comment: I didn't say it should be without JS, just without libraries.

Comment: Than, you have two options listed above.

Comment: Regarding XMLHttpRequest: I thought, it's not possible, because when I used it in a script tag, I got a warning "XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url}. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." Was it bacuse of a different reason?

Comment: That is because of security issues, search for CORS or JSONP to set it up

Comment: @philipp thank you.